# Snowflake SQL - Conditional Insert into satement only If there is no row with particular value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to do conditional insert in one table i.e

1. If the table's column does not particular value then insert row  based on
2. Where clause from other table
   I tried this query in snowflake but it throws error as Unexpected "status", for below query:

```
insert INTO
    when status not in ('not-tested','ok')
              then
      into test.log_t(filename) values (SELECT filename from
        test.tab_stg
                             where 
                             insert_f = 'Y'
                             and 
                             insert_f <> 'N' 
                             
  select distinct status from test.log_t;
```

status table
[image: status table]

Can some one please help?

log_t table
[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to make your question clear.

Comment: Added the table sample

Answer (score 0):

```
insert INTO test.log_t(filename)
SELECT filename 
from
    test.tab_stg
where 
    insert_f = 'Y'
    and 
    insert_f <> 'N' 
    and 
    status not in ('not-tested','ok');
```

Comment: Here challenge is the query shoul run only if status not in ('not-tested', 'OK') with where clause I believe it will update the table